# Unequal column numbers of test images sent to R from ImageJ via Bio7

Tags: r, image-processing, imagej, bio7

Today I discovered the marvel that is [Bio7](http://bio7.org/). This eclipse-like IDE combines R and [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/user-guide.pdf) and their website has [a tutorial](http://bio7.org/?p=2697&cpage=1#comment-2401) on how to do image feature extraction and ML with this combination.

[image]

I've followed through the tutorial, but instead of trying to classify parts of a single image, I'm dealing with > 100,000 images.

I've found that I can get conformable data for test and control but only if I do not select ROI's in the test data. While the data objects -- once passed to R and transformed with an appropriately specified `as.data.frame(matrix(unlist()))` statement, I have to wonder if I'm not losing a lot of value in terms of classification by not indicating the ROI's.

How can I get an R object that has 1 element (i.e. 1 matrix in a list of matrices, or whatever) per image (or per frame/slice of an Image Sequence) after specifying the ROI in the ROI manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyGB8uUjbWk&list=PLzCgXMp4TBsVKSRHZ8Q9y_3ZSlGl2kcrp&index=3

Apropos the 'Selection' button only transfers the selection coordinates and not the pixel data.

See:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2NflfBB2Tg

Comment: My mistake, I didn't mean to specify that button. I'll update the question.

Comment: Just for the record. If you transfer the stack with the 'IJ Raster Stack' action as a list (press no in the option dialog) the images will be transferred in the following mode: 1. as a list of matrix objects (if 'Double', 'Integer', 'Byte' transfer type selected). 2. As a list of 3 column R,G,B integer matrices (if 'RGB Byte' transfer type selected)

Comment: If you use the 'Pixel RM Stack' action create one ROI with the whole image selected (e.g., by pressing key 'a' to select all and the 't' to add the selection to the ROI Manager - or use the menus if that doesn't work). You get a matrix with all stack images as a column per ROI selection. In your case you only need the whole image selection ROI which results in one matrix with all loaded images of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "Pixel" action only transfers pixel data from one selection. This action is extra available if you don't want to use the ROI Manager of ImageJ.

If you import the image sequence you can e.g. transfer one ROI from the ROI Manager with the "Pixel RM Stack" action in the best data efficient data type.

Documentation:

http://bio7.org/manual/Main.html#toc-Subsection-4.4.3

http://bio7.org/manual/Main.html#toc-Subsubsection-4.4.3.1

In addition you can also transfer images (imported image sequence as a stack) with the Java API and then classify and store images one by one, e.g. with a Groovy or Jython script calling the Rserve API.

See example here:

http://bio7.622846.n4.nabble.com/Use-ProcessAviStack-Java-tp4640289p4640290.html

Apropos you can import the image sequence as a virtual stack (disk resident images) to save RAM memory, see:

https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-8.html